# Google App Script for Sheets - forEach works when running from editor but no data when running from time trigger

Tags: html, email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a function that sends an email in App script and using the HTML template to build the body of the email. The forEach loops through rows in a sheet.

When I run my function from the Editor, it all works fine. The email body contains the rows I expect to see. No errors.

When the time-driven trigger runs it, the output in the email is missing the data (tr and td) from my forEach loop which sits in the .html file/template.

When I look at the execution logs (time-driven trigger), there are no errors and the logs are consistent with the email body.

While testing, I set the trigger timer to "every 1 minute".

Here's the code.gs:

```
function sendScheduledEmailRFP() {
  Logger.log("function executed");
  /* Connect to spreadsheet */
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  var values = ss.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  const htmlTemplateRFP = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("rfpEmail");
  htmlTemplateRFP.values = values;
  const htmlForRfpEmail = htmlTemplateRFP.evaluate().getContent();

  MailApp.sendEmail(
    "email@address.com",
    "subject", 
    "Blabla", 
    { 
      htmlBody: htmlForRfpEmail
    }
  );
  Logger.log(htmlForRfpEmail);
}
```

Here's the .html code (only the forEach portion):

```
  <tbody>
    <? values.forEach(r => { 

      if(r[2] === "RFP" && r[9] !== "On hold"){ ?>
        <tr>
          <td style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: left; padding: 5px; font-size: 10px;">
            <?= r[5] ?>
          </td>
          <td style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: right; padding: 5px; font-size: 10px;">
            <?= r[13] ?>
          </td>
          <td style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: right; padding: 5px; font-size: 10px;">
            <?= r[27] ?>
          </td>
        </tr>
   <? 
      } 
    }) 
   ?>
  </tbody>
```

Here's the log output from the function when executed from the Time-Driven trigger:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
   <div>
     <div>
       <h3>Today's list</h3>
       <table style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid black; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; width: 300px;">
         <thead>
           <tr style="background-color: #ffd166;">
             <th colspan="3" style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: left; padding: 5px; font-size: 12px;">
               Today's list
             </th>
           </tr>
         </thead>
       <tbody>
       </tbody>
     </table>  
   </div>      
 </div>
```

I've already tried to delete the trigger and recreate one.. same issue. Help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use `getDataRange()` on a sheet, not on a spreadsheet

- If you do not specify a sheet, `getDataRange()` is retrieving by default the data range on the active sheet
- When you run a function on a time-driven trigger, the active sheet is always  defaulted to the first sheet of a spreadsheet.
- If you want the data range to be retrieved on the sheet `Data`, you need to modify your code as following:

From

```js
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  var values = ss.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
```

To

```js
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  var values = ws.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
```

**Side note:**

For troubleshooting it is always helpful to implement logs in strategic locations in your code. E.g. log `values` after retrieving them, log `r[2]` and  `r[9]`.

Comment: Thank you ziganotschka. This solved the issue. I feel silly for missing this error and thanks for the tip on troubleshooting.